# Cannot import ES2015 module

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to develop an npm library, but when I use it in another app, e.g.:

```
import React from 'react';
import SmallGrid from 'react-smallgrid';


export default class Library extends React.Component{
```

I get the following error:

```
$ grunt browserify
Running "browserify:jsx" (browserify) task
>> /Users/me/code/myapp/node_modules/react-smallgrid/src/smallgrid.jsx:1
>> import React from 'react';
>> ^
>> ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.
```

The [library](https://github.com/Tjorriemorrie/react-smallgrid/blob/master/src/smallgrid.jsx) starts with:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';


export default class SmallGrid extends React.Component{
```

Is there anybody here that knows what these horrible javascript errors mean?

Comment: How are you compiling it? Are you using babel?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson yes with `    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.2",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to import code from node_modules written in ES2015. You have to compile code in your library to ES5. For example using babel (via npm script):

```
"scripts": {
    "compile": "babel --presets es2015,stage-0 -d lib/ src/"
}
```

This script expects your ES2015 code to be placed in `src/` directory and outputs compiled code into `lib/` directory

Answer (score 2):

Your entry point to the library is `"main": "src/smallgrid.jsx"`.

What this means is that you're trying to serve the source files from your package rather than the compiled ones.

Change to `"main": "dist/js/smallgrid.js"` in your package.json